# Mapping Notation and Codomain

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, notation

I am new to the mapping idea. Are these true statements, given $f(x)=2$:

$f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R \\f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^+ \\f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb Z \\f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb   N$

etc,
etc,

$f:\mathbb R \rightarrow2$

Comment: All are true up to "etc, etc", but $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to 2$ is false. No matter what "2" is, exactly, it isn't a member of itself, so  $f(a) = 2 \notin 2$.

Comment: For the last one, rewrite it as $f:\mathbb{R}\to\{2\}$. A set mapping needs to have values in a set, and $2$ is not a set.

Comment: At the risk of being pedantic, I'll mention that even though all four of those top ones are valid codomains, they all technically represent *different* functions.  That is $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=2$ is a **different** function than $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb N$ defined by $f(x)=2$.